# Online and Offline synchronization of a MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a project with three other colleagues, that consists of basic forms (with pictures stored in it) who should be customizable.

The app is developped in c#, the problem is that it musts have to work in offline mode sometime. All the data were supposed to be stored in BSON documents until a connexion is disponible, but we recently learnt that there should be pictures in the form, and so we have to use gridFS and that is much more complicated.

I would like to know what you would do?
I thought of installing a mongo on the client et replicate on  the server, but I think that would be problematic if there are more than one client, or serializing the picture in only one file, or even find a system like SQLite if it exists for mongoDB.

All ideas are welcome !